# Class behaviour in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

The code work when use different no of parameter in function. How does classes work in typescript?

```
interface icar { 
getcar(name: string, age: string): void;
}

class Car implements icar{

    getcar() {
        console.log('anything');
    }

}

var newCar:any = new Car();
newCar.getcar('name');
```

Comment: What's the difference between a function accepting parameters but not using them internally, and not accepting those parameters in the first place? Nothing. The interface is compatible.

Comment: Remeber in `JS` in general you can just not send parameters to a function - missing arguments by default would be `undefined` - so no problem for an interface implementation with less arguments as far as consistency.

Comment: @deceze if we only worked with function without classes then typescript gave error on different number of function  parameter and arguments but we use the function in classes then typescript do not gave error on different number of function parameter and arguments as shown above in code. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *implementer* of the `interface` is free to accept *fewer* parameters than the interface defines. The reason is simply that the function might not want to use the value of the parameter in the first place, so omitting it doesn't change anything about how the function works. Passing more arguments than defined parameters doesn't cause a runtime error either. Further, the function might internally use `arguments` instead of parameters in the function signature; another reason why Typescript allows omitting of parameters.

However, the *caller* of the function must pass the arguments defined in the interface signature. Whether the concrete implementation uses the arguments or not, if the caller doesn't abide by the defined interface, then there isn't any guarantee that the implementation *should* work.

The reason Typescript isn't raising an error on `newCar.getcar('name')` is that you've overridden the type inference with `:any`, that causes Typescript to suspend all type checking on `newCar`. Remove `:any` and Typescript will complain about a mismatching number of arguments.